# Why is my store procedure taking long time to give data

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is my store procedure.

I am using Sum to calculate total amount.

Since my amount is in varchar so im converting it to int.

I cannot change anything in my table datatype

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[usp_GetBtReport]

as
Begin
Declare @TotalTransactionAmount decimal,@BalanceTransferDone decimal,@BalanceTransferPending decimal,

select @TotalTransactionAmount=  sum(CONVERT(decimal, Amount)) from tbl_Transaction 
with(nolock)   where Status='Success' and Type='Withdraw' 
and  DATEDIFF(D,CONVERT(date,createdDate),GETDATE())<7

select @BalanceTransferDone= sum(CONVERT(decimal, Amount))  from tbl_Transaction
with(nolock)   where Status='Success' and Type='Withdraw' 
and  DATEDIFF(D,CONVERT(date,createdDate),GETDATE())<7 and isnull(IsBalanceTransferDone,0)=1

select @BalanceTransferPending= sum(CONVERT(decimal, Amount))  from tbl_Transaction
with(nolock)   where Status='Success' and Type='Withdraw' 
and  DATEDIFF(D,CONVERT(date,createdDate),GETDATE())<7 and isnull(IsBalanceTransferDone,0)=0

select  
@TotalTransactionAmount as 'TotalTransactionAmount',@BalanceTransferDone as 'BalanceTransferDone',@BalanceTransferPending
as 'BalanceTransferPending',

end
```

Since i am working with large data
Above store procedure is giving me response approximately in 5 seconds.
How i can improve performance of this store procedure?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Check your execution plan of your query and create indexes.

Comment: Have you tried to rewrite DATEDIFF(D,CONVERT(date,createdDate),GETDATE())<7 to something like createdDate between dateadd(dd,-7,getdate())and getdate()

Comment: @Sergey your suggestion is making difference of 1 to 2 seconds, now  I am getting response in 3 to 4 seconds

Comment: Have you tried to combine my suggestion and the answer below?

Comment: Stop splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). And how much effort do you REALLY save by using `DATEDIFF(D,` rather than `DATEDIFF(DAY,`? But how much more readable and self-documenting is the latter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try  reducing the number of query  using

```
select @TotalTransactionAmount=  sum(CONVERT(decimal, Amount)) 
     , BalanceTransferDone= sum(case when is null IsBalanceTransferDone THEN CONVERT(decimal, Amount) ELSE 0 END) 
    , @BalanceTransferPending=um(case when is NOT null IsBalanceTransferDone THEN CONVERT(decimal, Amount) ELSE 0 END) 
FROM bl_Transaction with(nolock)   
where Status='Success' and Type='Withdraw' and  DATEDIFF(D,CONVERT(date,createdDate),GETDATE())<7
```

and check for indexes matching the where clause column  (not in function)

and as suggeted  by @Larnu avoid date convertion too expensive for performance

```
select @TotalTransactionAmount=  sum(CONVERT(decimal, Amount)) 
     , BalanceTransferDone= sum(case when is null IsBalanceTransferDone THEN CONVERT(decimal, Amount) ELSE 0 END) 
    , @BalanceTransferPending=um(case when is NOT null IsBalanceTransferDone THEN CONVERT(decimal, Amount) ELSE 0 END) 
FROM bl_Transaction with(nolock)   
where Status='Success' 
  and Type='Withdraw' 
   and CreateDate >= DATEADD(DAY, -6, CONVERT(date,GETDATE()))
```

Comment: Changing `DATEDIFF(D,CONVERT(date,createdDate),GETDATE())<7` to something like `CreateDate >= DATEADD(DAY, -6, CONVERT(date,GETDATE()))` would be likely be a big improvement too, as it'll be SARGable.

Comment: answer updated  adding the @Larnu suggestion too

Comment: I was going to add this comment to the OP, but the whole datediff nonsense is an unnecessary way of saying CREATED>=GETDATE()-7